# When setting text on a TextView it takes way too long to display the text on screen

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

I'm setting the text on a text view to a String that is 14,000,000  characters long.

This takes anywere from 1 to 5 minutes to load on screen(depending on device). Any Ideas how I can speed this up?

Here is the relevant code:

```
  responseView.text = requestResponsePair.second
 .....................
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.salesrabbit.android.sales.universal.features.lumberjack.TextDisplayFragment">

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/request_label"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/request_label_string"
     android:textSize="20sp"/>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/text_view_request"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/response_label"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/response_label_string"
     android:textSize="20sp"/>

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/text_view_response"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Approach One**

Recently, Google announced the [`PrecomputedText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/PrecomputedText) which is available for SDK level 28 and above. Along with that, the [`PrecomputedTextCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/text/PrecomputedTextCompat) has been released which is available for SDK 21 to 27. I haven't try it yet but there is a Medium article from [Chris Craik](https://medium.com/@chriscraik) called "[*Prefetch Text Layout in RecyclerView*](https://medium.com/google-developers/prefetch-text-layout-in-recyclerview-4acf9103f438)" which explains how to make use of it and how much workload gets off the UI thread without missing any frames.

Snippet from article

***Precomputing***

```
val precomputedText : Spannable = PrecomputedTextCompat.create(expensiveText, params)
```

***Set precomputed text to TextView***

```
TextViewCompat.setPrecomputedText(myTextView, precomputedText)
```

Make sure to read the docs, as some posting to a background thread is required.

**Approach Two**

Split your text into small chunks or paragraphs. Put it into a list and use a simple RecyclerView to show each item in the list. It's simple and you will get for free good performance as RecyclerView will render and process the items that are visible to the user.

Also, make sure to listen to the [Episode 90: Spanspanspanspan](http://androidbackstage.blogspot.com/2018/05/episode-90-spanspanspanspan.html) of the [Android Developers Backstage](http://androidbackstage.blogspot.com/) podcast, it is hosted by developers of the Android Engineering team.

Answer (score 3):

**Use PrecomputedText**

Using [PrecomputedText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/PrecomputedText) is one of the best approaches here. Read [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51411805/3653330) by [Giorgos Neokleous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3330058/giorgos-neokleous).

**Turn off hyphenation**

Turn off hyphenation also helps to improve performance significantly. You can do that by setting `android:hyphenationFrequency="none"` for a specific TextView or overriding that property for the whole application:

```
<!-- res/values/styles.xml -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- ... -->
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/AppTextView</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTextView" parent="BaseAppTextView">
    <item name="android:hyphenationFrequency">none</item>
</style>

<style name="BaseAppTextView" parent="android:Widget.TextView"/>


<!-- res/values-21/styles.xml -->
<style name="BaseAppTextView" parent="android:Widget.Material.TextView"/>
```

---

Also take a look at few links:

- [Use Android Text Like a Pro](https://youtu.be/vXqwRhjd7b4) presentation by **Siyamed Sinir** from the **Android Dev Summit '18** where he describes both approaches with some details.
- [Prefetch Text Layout in RecyclerView](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/prefetch-text-layout-in-recyclerview-4acf9103f438) article in Android Developers blog that can help make your RecyclerView faster.

Answer (score 0):

That text is far too long. You should divide them by \n (divide into paragraphs) and put each paragraph into a textview in a recyclerview.

Tradeoff is that users cannot select all of the text or in-between paragraphs but i believe at the end it will be a better UX.

Then you should apply Precomputedtext.